# Can Python print out the line by line flow (or order) of a run?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a Python assignment where I need to describe the order in which Python ran the program by identifying line numbers. This is to help us understand the try/except and errors.

I'm pretty sure I've achieved this through inspection, but I wanted to know if Python has the ability to print out the flow by line numbers so I may check my work. If Python does not have this built in, is there a way in which I could do this?

I am working with Python 2.7.

Comment: A better way to do this is by stepping through the code with pdb  http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html

Answer (score 2):

Try the [trace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html) module:

Example:

test.py:

```
def main():
    print("Hello, world")

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

Then on the command line:

```
$ python -m trace --trace test.py 
 --- modulename: test, funcname: <module>
test.py(1): def main():
test.py(4): if __name__ == '__main__': 
test.py(5):     main()
 --- modulename: test, funcname: main
test.py(2):     print("Hello, world")
Hello, world
 --- modulename: trace, funcname: _unsettrace
trace.py(80):         sys.settrace(None)
```

It has a handful of other options that might be useful as well, such as `--listfuncs`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [trace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html) module in the python standard library.